# CMAKE - Changing outdir macro through cmake

Tags: directory, cmake, visual-studio-2005, output

Reading others questions here I found that is possible to change the outdir macro inside de visual studio. I really searched but didn't found/understand how to do it.

It's kind simple. I just want to change the Project property -> Configuration Properties -> General -> Output Directory. Because I know that will change the outdir macro.

I understand that is throught set_target_property using some kind of cmake PROPERTY but I really didn't found how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, what worked for me was placing the full path on the target_link_libraries with debug prefix and optimized prefix to point release config and relwithdebinfo config to release path and debug to debug. I also took off the link_directories... I don't if I didn't understand but it worked for me!

Comment: Can you please post the part of cmakelist.txt for reference here.

Comment: Sorry, company code and I don't have access anymore.

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty straightforward as you suspected.  You need to look at the [`ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#prop_tgt%3aARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY), [`LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#prop_tgt%3aLIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY), and [`RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#prop_tgt%3aRUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY) target properties to modify the outdir path.

These all have config-specific variants too (e.g. `ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG`) and can all be initialised by the global CMake variables of the same name with a `CMAKE_` prepended.

So, you can do e.g.

```
set_target_properties(MyExe PROPERTIES RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY <custom path>)
```

or, to affect all targets,

```
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY <custom path>)
```

NB. From the docs:

> Multi-configuration generators (VS, Xcode) append a per-configuration subdirectory to the specified directory.

Here's an example showing this behaviour.  It writes its own trivial C++ source files, so all you should need to do is copy this to a folder, invoke CMake then try building the resultant solution in Debug, Release, MinSizeRel and RelWithDebInfo.  Tested with VS2012.  The executable always ends up in `<build dir>/Exes/Debug` regardless of build type, and similarly the library is always in `<build dir>/Libs/Debug`.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11 FATAL_ERROR)
project(Example)

file(WRITE lib.hpp "void Print();\n")
file(WRITE lib.cpp "#include<iostream>\nvoid Print() { std::cout << \"Hello World\\n\"; }\n")
file(WRITE main.cpp "#include \"lib.hpp\"\nint main() { Print(); return 0; }\n")

set(ArchiveOutputDir ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Libs/Debug)
set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG ${ArchiveOutputDir})
set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_MINSIZEREL ${ArchiveOutputDir})
set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE ${ArchiveOutputDir})
set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELWITHDEBINFO ${ArchiveOutputDir})

set(RuntimeOutputDir ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Exes/Debug)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG ${RuntimeOutputDir})
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_MINSIZEREL ${RuntimeOutputDir})
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE ${RuntimeOutputDir})
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELWITHDEBINFO ${RuntimeOutputDir})

add_library(MyLib lib.cpp lib.hpp)
add_executable(MyExe main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(MyExe MyLib)
```

Comment: I tried with all of then. Didn't work, I'll read more about then but just to make sure.

What I'm trying to do is change that $(outdir) macro that is set as Release or Debug. It's add automaticaly on the Additional Library Dependecies. For example, I wish to change all to be always Debug, doesn't mather if I'm really on Debug on VS

Comment: Did you set the `CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG` variable (or whichever) *before* your `add_library` or `add_executable` calls?  These default CMake variables are used to initialise the local target properties at the point where they are declared.  To have e.g. all your libs created in the same directory regardless of build type, simply set all versions of `CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_<build-type>` to the same value.

Comment: After a lot of days trying, didn't work.

I have this:
c:\dir\anotherDir\Release (Release Build)

But I want This:
c:\dir\anotherDir\Debug (Release Build)

On the Additional Library Directories

Comment: I've added an example CMakeLists.txt.  I've also just noticed that you've tagged your question VS2005.  If this doesn't work for you, I imagine that the version of VS could be the problem.  This certainly works for VS2010 onwards.

Comment: In the end, what worked for me was putting the full path on the target_link_libraries with debug prefix and optimized prefix to point release config and relwithdebinfo config to release path and debug to debug.
I also took off the link_directories... I don't if I didn't understand but it worked for me! Thanks for the help! I really appreciate!

Comment: So I delete the link_directories and put the full path and lib name on the target_link_libraries...

Comment: @KaiqueGomes: if the issue is resolved, please select an answer. I do not understand why you do not select an answer for your questions...